# Exclude multiple directorys with GLOB

Tags: php, glob

GLOB has a flag das is called `GLOB_ONLYDIR` what is actaully good.

I have a diretory e.g

```
/this/is/my/seek/root/
```

there are several directorys and files in there. Lets say

```
aaa/
bbb/
ccc/
ddd/
test.txt
foobar.svg
```

to get all directorys I go for

```
$root = '/this/is/my/seek/root/';
$dirs = glob($root . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

This brings me up all directorys. But now I want to exclude directory `bbb` & `ccc`

I tried a lot but could not get any satisfying result. I thought about using `GLOB_BRACE` as well, to give some additional informations... but couldnt get my expected result. And obviously the documentation is very poor or i'm to stupid to read it right :)

So my question is:

**How can i select all folders, excapt one or two, in one glob command?**

Comment: I don't think you can do that, you'll need to filter them out of the results.

Comment: I tried to come up with a regex, but I just came to the conclusion it's easier to filter after the fact imo

Comment: @alistaircol thats very kind :D thank you. I solved it atm with an `array_filter( $array, callbackFunction )` where `$array` is the result of the glob. But i still miss some functionality in the glob :)